# Variable size matrix in MatLab

Tags: matlab, matrix

For part of my Statics homework, I have to create a MATLAB function that will take "n" forces acting on a system and turn them into an nx3 matrix. Yes, the "n"s are intentional, the amount of rows is supposed to change with the amount of forces. From there, I need to be able to make it an augmented matrix and solve, for a resultant force, yada yada...I just have no clue where to start setting up a matrix with an unknown amount of rows. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Then just allocate an `nx3` matrix when you know the value of `n`...

Answer (score 1):

If you can avoid creating the matrix until you know the value of `n` then you should.
At that stage you'd just allocate it doing

```
mat = nan(n,3);  % or zeros(n,3) if you'd prefer.
```

And then change the elements doing

```
mat(row_to_change,:) = new_1_by_3_values;
```

However, if you really need to dynamically resize the matrix - which is sometimes required, but should be avoided if possible for efficiency reasons - then you'd initialize the variable using,

```
mat = []; % empty matrix
```

and then anytime you want to append new data to the matrix you can do either

```
mat = [mat; new_1_by_3_values];
```

or

```
mat(end+1,:) = new_1_by_3_values;
```

Comment: Please don’t recommend `mat = [mat; new_1_by_3_values]`, it is highly inefficient. The other form (`end+1`) is the correct one. The difference is not minor. It is huge! See this Q&A pair to understand the difference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48351041/matlab-adding-array-elements-iteratively-time-behavior