# Preallocate space for array with known maximum size

Tags: matlab

Is there anyway to allot a fixed chunk of memory for a growing/decreasing array in a loop? I know the range of sizes it can have, i.e. the min and max dimensions.

I could just allot a matrix of max size as follows,
`A = zeros(max,max);`
but here's the problem with that approach. I have matrix multiplication and inverse operations inside the loop. On top of that, I am using slicing operation (complete row/column selections)

```
A[:,i]  = data(i).x;
B = A\P; 
C = A*W;
```

The allocation of maximum size does not go well these operations (**size mismatch error**).

So, I am trying to allocate a memory chunk corresponding to a max dimension, but want to utilize only a part of it.

I know this can be achieved using loops for matrix operations, instead of vector operations in Matlab but that would be inefficient. (in fact I am not sure how the inverse operation would be implemented in a loop).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No, you cannot control the memory size and array size independently in MATLAB. MATLAB does allocate a larger space for an array if it increases incrementally in a loop, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48351041/matlab-adding-array-elements-iteratively-time-behavior/48353598#48353598

Comment: There is no simple solution, especially when it comes to matrices. For a vector you could index the part you actually want, but indexing a matrix on both dimensions is significant slower (non consecutive memory). Before you waste your time, did you actually profile the code to see if the growing / shrinking is critical to the performance? With some matrix operations inside, I could imagine it does not really matter.

Comment: Thank you guys for the replies. @Daniel It needs to grow and shrink. I get the data in batches (different sizes) and update the previous calculation accordingly. I can potentially cut the data to the minimum size every batch but that wouldn't be acceptable to some people.

Comment: @Cris That brings up an interesting point. If Matlab doubles the allocated memory, only if we could access this 2x factor and customize it we could allocate custom memory size.

Comment: But note that growing a matrix in height will always require data copy, it is only growing a matrix width or growing a vector that can make use of that type of optimization.