# Add element to the front of a vector, without knowing if it is a row or column vector?

Tags: arrays, matlab

If i'm adding a newvlaue to a row vector x, it would be

```
x = [newvlue, x] % use of ,
```

but if to a column vector x, it would be

```
x = [newvlue; x] % use of ;
```

so i have to know in advance if it's a row or column vector in order to perform this front insertion. But i might not always know as x is meant to be a user inputs. So every time i need to perform this row vector or column vector check beforehand. However, let's say I don't really want to care if it's a row or column vector, I just need to add one element at the front of the array. Is there any elegant way to write the code?

Comment: I'm not sure but adding to the end of vector should be more efficient than adding to the front

Comment: @rahnema1 haha... that, of course, is the answer :) (see below...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to check for the dimension of the input:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
% or
x = [1; 2; 3]
new = 0;

% flexible concatenation
y = cat(~(size(x,1) > 1) + 1, new ,x)
```

### Explanation

```
d = size(x,1) > 1   % check if column (=1) or row vector (>1)
z = ~(d) + 1        % results in either 1 or 2 for column or row vector
                    % as input for cat
y = cat(z, new ,x)  % concatenate in correct dimension
```

or by using [**`isrow`**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isrow.html) as suggested in [ThomasIsCoding's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61210278/2605073), but I guess it almost does the same:

```
z = isrow(x) + 1;
```

---

In any way you should use [**`isvector`**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isvector.html) to check, whether the input is actually a vector and not a matrix. But actually I would recommend to convert any input, row or column vector, into a column vector with

```
x = x(:)
```

to allow for consisting coding within your underlying function.

Comment: Most important, the `x = x(:)`. Convert all vectors to a known orientation makes it much easier.

Answer (score 2):

I like one-liners, try this one

```
a(1:end+1)=[100;a(:)]
```

works for both row and column matrices.

Answer (score 2):

As [@rahnema1 said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61210013/add-element-to-the-front-of-a-vector-without-knowing-if-it-is-a-row-or-column-v#comment108291448_61210013), just add the new value to the end:

```
x = flip(x); 
x(end+1) = newvalue; 
x = flip(x);
```

Comment: You can notice that adding to the end of vector is done with [amortized constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48351041/matlab-adding-array-elements-iteratively-time-behavior) time while concatenation requires reallocation.  But your method would be the most efficient answer if flip is done before and after a loop where a high mumber of appendings is performed.

Comment: @rahnema1 I still think Daniel's and FangQ's answers would be faster, especially if the number of elements to be inserted is known beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can define your custom function like below

```
function y = addhead(x,val)
  if isrow(x)
    y = horzcat(val,x);
  else
    y = vertcat(val,x);
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use indexing to shift all elements by 1, then insert the new element at the beginning.

```
x(2:end+1)=x;
x(1)=7;
```

Comment: That's too simple.