# Concatenate cell array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

In Matlab you can concatenate arrays by saying:

```
a=[];
a=[a,1];
```

How do you do something similar with a cell array?

```
a={};
a={a,'asd'};
```

The code above keeps on nesting cells within cells. I just want to append elements to the cell array. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: `a{end+1}='asd'`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `a` and `b` are cell arrays, then you concatenate them in the same way you concatenate other arrays: using `[]`:

```
>> a={1,'f'}
a =
  1×2 cell array
    {[1]}    {'f'}

>> b={'q',5}
b =
  1×2 cell array
    {'q'}    {[5]}

>> [a,b]
ans =
  1×4 cell array
    {[1]}    {'f'}    {'q'}    {[5]}
```

You can also use the functional form, [`cat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.cat.html), in which you can select along which dimension you want to concatenate:

```
>> cat(3,a,b)
  1×2×2 cell array
ans(:,:,1) = 
    {[1]}    {'f'}

ans(:,:,2) = 
    {'q'}    {[5]}
```

To append a single element, you can do `a=[a,{1}]`, but this is not efficient (see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48351041/7328782)). Instead, do `a{end+1}=1` or `a(end+1)={1}`.

---

Remember that a cell array is just an array, like any other. You use the same tools to manipulate them, including indexing, which you do with `()`. The `()` indexing returns the same type of array as the one you index into, so it returns a cell array, even if you index just a single element. Just about every value in MATLAB is an array, including `6`, which is a 1x1 double array.

The `{}` syntax is used to create a cell array, and to extract its content: `a{1}` is not a cell array, it extracts the contents of the first element of the array.

`{5, 8, 3}` is the same as `[{5}, {8}, {3}]`. `5` is a double array, `{5}` is a cell array containing a double array.

`a{5} = 0` is the same as `a(5) = {0}`.

Comment: Nice answer. Nitpick: I believe it is "Every _variable_ is an array". Functions, methods, etc. are not.

Comment: @StewieGriffin Thanks for pointing that out. I guess it's a bit more nuanced than I made it out to be. A function handle also is not an array, so not even all variables are arrays. I guess I shouldn't generalize... :)

Comment: @Sardar just pointed out that, yes, a function handle is technically also an array. It's just that you can't put more than one handle in the array. So a function handle is array limited to 1x1.