# why am I getting a vertcat error in my matlab code?

Tags: xcode, matlab, error-handling

When I try to run this code I keep getting this error message and I'm not sure how to fix it!

> Error using vertcat Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not
> consistent.
>
> Error in ListofPictures (line 15) FileNameList = [FileNameList;
> Fileinfo(imagenumber).name];

Here is the code:

```
%Creates filenamelist or converets images from rgb to grayscale based on
%user input


cd (FolderMain)

choice = input('Enter 0 to convert RGB to Greyscale, Enter 1 to create filelist, Enter 2 for to do       both');
FolderName = input('What folder are the Images contained in? ','s');

Fileinfo = dir(FolderName);  %obtain list of images from folder + "\*.tif"
[x,~] = size(Fileinfo); %optains the number of images and sets it = to x
imagenumber = 1;
FileNameList = []; 
while imagenumber <= x %create FileNameList 
FileNameList = [FileNameList; Fileinfo(imagenumber).name];
imagenumber = imagenumber + 1;
end
[Lengthx,Lengthy] = size(FileNameList);

if (choice >= 1)
cd (FolderName)
[FileNameBase,PathNameBase] = uiputfile('filenamelist.mat','Save as "filenamelist" in image directory     (recommended)');
cd(PathNameBase)
save(FileNameBase,'FileNameList');

 end
%Converts RGB to Greyscale and Saves it in a new folder
%RGB converter
%Start with current directory set to Matlab folder that holds the Image
%folder 
cd (FolderMain)
%Converts RGB to Greyscale and Saves it in a new folder
if (choice ~= 1)
if FolderName == 0
    FolderName = input('What folder are the Images contained in? ','s');
end
FolderNameNew= convertCharsToStrings(FolderName) + 'greyscale';
cd(FolderName)
NewFolder = mkdir(FolderNameNew);
addpath(genpath(FolderNameNew))
n=1;
while (n<=Lengthx)
RGB = imread(FileNameList(n,1:Lengthy));
GreyImage = rgb2gray(RGB);
cd(FolderNameNew);
ImageName = "grey" + convertCharsToStrings(FileNameList(n,1:Lengthy));
imwrite(GreyImage, ImageName)
cd ..
n=n+1;
end
cd (FolderMain)
cd (FolderName)
FolderName = FolderNameNew;

Fileinfo = dir(FolderName + "\*.tif");  %obtain list of images from folder
[x,~] = size(Fileinfo); %optains the number if images and sets it = to x
imagenumber = 1;
FileNameList = []; 
while imagenumber <= x %create FileNameList 
FileNameList = [FileNameList; Fileinfo(imagenumber).name];
imagenumber = imagenumber + 1;
end
cd (FolderName)
[FileNameBase,PathNameBase] = uiputfile('filenamelist.mat','Save as "filenamelist" in image directory     (recommended)');
cd(PathNameBase)
save(FileNameBase,'FileNameList');
end
Choice = input('Would you like to continue to image processing Enter 1 for yes, 0 for no.');
if Choice == 1
DIC
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`Fileinfo(imagenumber).name` is most likely a character array which has length equal to the number of characters in the file name.  When you try to concatonate them Matlab expects all the file names to be the same length.

You can address this two ways.  One is to convert `FileNameList` to be a cell or convert the file names to be strings.  I prefer the latter, strings were introduced in 2016b.

You would do it by making this change to line 15:

```
FileNameList = [FileNameList; string(Fileinfo(imagenumber).name)];
```

To convert to a cell, wrap the `Fileinfo` in `{...}`.  Like this:

```
FileNameList = {};
....
FileNameList = [FileNameList; {Fileino(imagenumber).name}];
```

However, without access to your files, I can't be sure this is actual error.

Comment: A quick note: it is significantly more efficient to extend an array with `FileNameList(end + 1) = ...` rather than `FileNameList = [FileNameList, ...]`. See this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48351041/7328782

Comment: It would be easier to get rid of the loop entirely and do something like `FileNameList = {Fileinfo(:).name};`, which avoids growing the array inside a loop too.